# Problema ao receber um valor de um radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Estou começando a mexer com AngularJS e tive um pequeno problema ao mexer com *radio buttons*. Meu código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Temperature Converter</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="temp-conv" ng-controller="converter">

<h1>Temperature Converter</h1>
    <h2>Temperatura de entrada</h2>
    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="valor"><br>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="ent" value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit<br>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="ent" value="kelvin">Kelvin<br>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="ent" ng-value="celsius">Celsius<br>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="ent" value="rankine">Rankine<br>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="ent" value="reaumur">Réaumur<br>
        <br>
    <h2>Temperatura de saída</h2>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="sai" value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit<br>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="sai" value="kelvin">Kelvin<br>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="sai" value="celsius">Celsius<br>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="sai" value="rankine">Rankine<br>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="sai" value="reaumur">Réaumur<br>
        {{ valor }}
    </form>


</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

E meu JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('temp-conv', []);

app.controller('converter', function($scope){
if ($scope.ent === "celsius") {
    $scope.valor = 3;
} else {
    $scope.valor = "4";
}
});
```

Esse Js é só um pequeno teste para ver se o valor está sendo passado, e não está funcionando.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow, forneça mais detalhes de seu problema para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique a documentação de como instanciar o radiobutton em angular para fazer uso da api.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.radioButton